# Exp or iat time in rest_framework_simplejwt token

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

How to get jwt token expiration time or issuing time, in Django rest framework simple jwt library. I need to pass token expiration time in response to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom serializer. If it is the `TokenObtainPairView` view for which you want to return the token's expiry time, for example, create a custom view that inherits from `TokenObtainPairView` and a custom serializer that inherits from [`TokenObtainPairSerializer`](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/41f4daf66943161f463afcb8f808f144e5b6b592/rest_framework_simplejwt/serializers.py#L64).

For example:

In your `urlpatterns`:

```
path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

Custom view:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Custom serializer:

```
from datetime import datetime

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        # Add custom data here

        data['access_token_lifetime'] = str(refresh.access_token.lifetime)
        data['access_token_expiry'] = str(datetime.now() + refresh.access_token.lifetime)

        if api_settings.UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN:
            update_last_login(None, self.user)

        return data
```